# Function to copy and paste the last data of the last row of a column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

below is my code on copying and pasting the data of the last row of a column. it works on the command button but if i make it as a function, it's not working. it gives a 0 or false result. please check. thanks.

```
    Function CopyCell()

    Application.Volatile True
    Dim eRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Weekly Score")
    eRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(eRow, "N").Copy
    .Range("AG3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    ENd Function
```

Comment: it works find i see no erros

Comment: Do you try to call this from a cell? You can't copy, paste, or modify in any way other cells with a UDF called from a cell. [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787)

Comment: An UDF should not (and I think even can't) write to other cells. An UDF should only return a value hence it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this assign a MyFunction to your button

```
Option Explicit
Sub MyFunction()
   Call CopyCell
End Sub

Function CopyCell()
Application.Volatile True
    Dim eRow    As Integer
    Dim i       As Integer

    With Sheets("Weekly Score")
        eRow = .Cells(Rows.count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(eRow, "N").copy
        .Range("AG3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an UDF modify the function as such:

```
Public Function CopyCell()
    Application.Volatile True
    Dim eRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Weekly Score")
      eRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
      CopyCell =  .Cells(eRow, "N").Value
    End With
End Function
```

Otherwise lose the `Volatile` and change the `Function` to a `Sub and simply call it manually:

```
Sub CopyCell()

    Dim eRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Weekly Score")
     eRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
     .Cells(eRow, "N").Copy
     .Range("AG3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Remember that `Application.Volatile True` will cause the function to recalculate whenever any Calculation is carried out. This may seriously impact performance.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The first one you provide works already. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. Please mark my post as answer then to close this thread.